# Where check string is AES crypt in C?

Tags: c, encryption, aes, crypt

Where is correct checking char* array is AES 128/192/256 crypt, or non crypt - is text?
not use OpenSSL, pls.

Comment: Do you mean, how to distinguish ciphertext from plaintext? If yes, then this depends on the content of the plaintext. If it is text, then you can do statistical analysis.

Comment: If you want a solution without guessing involved: Impossible. AES ciphertext and eg. (plain) random numbers are not distinguishable (in fact, AES-CTR is a good PRNG in certain conditions)

Comment: This question makes no sense. Please rephrase it.

Comment: ok, AES string is binsry? my bee yes. Where check binary or text string ?

Answer (score 1):

tldr: If you want a 100%-working solution, it´s completely impossible.

Long version:

First, stop thinking "binary vs text". That´s not how it works.
AES ciphertext surely is binary data in the computer, but "text" is too.

If you want do distinguish AES ciphertext from other non-AES data, it´s impossible because:

- AES ciphertext can be some unreadable gargabe, but it can be a poem of Goethe too.
  Every possible data thing can be ("is") a AES ciphertext for some plaintext with some key.
- Non-AES data can be as much unreadable garbage as AES data. (Pseudo-) Random bytes as example: AES with proper input is an excellent random byte generator.

The other way round; if you want to distinguish proper and sane human-readable text from other things, it´s impossible because: There is no law or something what "text" is in your computer.
If you want to search for english letters, consider following points:

- As said above, readable words can be AES ciphertext too.
- English letters? What´s about German, Japanese, old Greek, Russian...?
- How are letters mapped to bytes? ISO88591, UTF16LE with BOM, EBCDIC, own mappings...?
- What´s about file formats like MS Word *.doc? In it, there´s text
  too, yet it´s binary "garbage" data. Or compression algorithms: Gzip,
  Rar etc. doesn´t make text less sane.
- If you finally extracted proper letters, how do you know if it isn´t something like "miodsjoiusdJf"? Recognizing words and their meaning is a very big topic on it´s own, and nearly everything in it is guesswork.